# Monotonicity of an optimizer

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let us consider an optimization problem over $[0,1]$. That is, we are given two continuous functions 
$$
 f,g:[0,1]^2\to \Bbb R
$$
such that

1. $f(x,y)$ is non-decreasing in $x$ and non-increasing in $y$;
2. $g(x,y)$ is non-increasing in $x$ and non-decreasing in $y$.

Denote $x^*(y):=\max\left( \operatorname{Argmax}\limits_{x\in [0,1]}f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)\right)$. What are sufficient conditions for $x^*$ to be non-decreasing?

Comment: Why do you need $\sup$? Since the functions are continuous and the interval closed, can't you use $\max$ (in the definition of $x^*$?

Comment: @Stefanos: thanks, you are right: the argmax set would be compact, hence admitting the maximal element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In economics the lattice approach is becoming popular. One sufficient condition for the maximizer to be nondecreasing in the parameters is that the objective function to be maximized is supermodular in $x$ and has increasing differences in $x,y$. See Theorem 5 (and others) in [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2951479). The techniques they describe are due to [Topkis](http://www.jstor.org/stable/169636).

Comment: Theorem 4 seems to give necessary and sufficient conditions, looks like a useful results - thanks!